# Some questions about householder reflection

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

[question 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfuDe.png)

[question 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucH6c.png)

[material from the note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYYMe.png)

I was so confused by the vector "y", why would it have different signs for Q1 and Q2 matrices in this case? I feel like vector "a" doesn't change at all so should the sign stay the same, could this be explained to me please?

Comment: There are [different reasons](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/1273570) why links to pictures aren’t great. It’s probably better to replicate the formulae from there using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) providing links only for reference.